# Knowing whether the robot is delocalised or not by observing relevant data

Tags: navigation, mapping, localization, amcl, laserscan

The way that we know if a robot is delocalised is by opening RViz and observing the laser's `scan` data with respect to the static map on the `map` frame. When it is delocalised, we can see that the scan is not matching the map that was set, and the obstacles on the scan data are deviated by some angle with respect to the obstacles on the map.

Now while this is easy to tell with our eyes, I wanted to ask if there is a way to find this out by observing data? Perhaps observing the `laser` -> `map` transform or something similar to that?